# How to optimise dispatch queue creation

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I am trying to implement a function which creates my custom high priority serial queue to be accessed in various objects similarly to `dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)`

To be sure that this queue is created only once I'm using dispatch once pattern. But I'm experiencing the performance problem. My function is three times slower. Here is the code:

```
dispatch_queue_t dispatch_get_custom_serial_queue() {
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    static dispatch_queue_t CustomSerialQueue = nil;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        CustomSerialQueue = dispatch_queue_create("custom.serial.queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
        dispatch_set_target_queue(CustomSerialQueue, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0));
    });
    return CustomSerialQueue;
}
```

Here is the test:

```
- (void)testQueueCreation
{
    CFAbsoluteTime startTime;

    NSLog(@"****************************");

    startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_custom_serial_queue();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i ++) {
        dispatch_sync(queue, ^{
            //
        });
    }
    NSLog(@"assign queue once:\t %f seconds", CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime);

    startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i ++) {
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_custom_serial_queue(), ^{
            //
        });
    }
    NSLog(@"get queue each time:\t %f seconds", CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime);

    startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i ++) {
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
            //
        });
    }
    NSLog(@"get global queue each time:\t %f seconds", CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime);

    NSLog(@"****************************");
}
```

And this is the result:

```
****************************
assign queue once: 0.035383 seconds
get queue each time: 0.112233 seconds
get global queue each time: 0.044906 seconds
****************************
```

What do I miss and how to make this function faster?

Comment: So you're saying it takes 112 nanoseconds to call `dispatch_get_custom_serial_queue` and you're worried that's going to be your bottleneck?

Comment: @robmayoff Of course not. But it is always interesting to learn more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dispatch_get_global_queue doesn't use dispatch_once. The function just gets a static variable.

- http://opensource.apple.com/source/libdispatch/libdispatch-339.92.1/src/queue.c
- http://opensource.apple.com/source/libdispatch/libdispatch-339.92.1/src/queue_internal.h

I think `dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_custom_serial_queue(); and dispatch_sync(queue,` is a good idea for this case.

Comment: I forgot that it's open source. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make `dispatch_get_custom_serial_queue` faster, get rid of the `dispatch_once`.  Create the queue in `main` before calling `UIApplicationMain` or `NSApplicationMain` to guarantee it'll exist later when needed.